# How to specify selector for kubectl service creation?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to specify selector while creating service with kubectl directly like in command below ?

```
    ~ $ kubectl create service clusterip headless-svc --tcp=80:80 --clusterip='None' --selector="app=multitool" --dry-run -o yaml
Error: unknown flag: --selector
```

Obviously I can modify yaml file, e.g.

```
    ~ $ kubectl create service clusterip headless-svc --tcp=80:80 --clusterip='None' --dry-run -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: headless-svc
  name: headless-svc
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: 80-80
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: headless-svc
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

But Im curious if it possible to do during svc creation ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 11):

`kubectl create service` does not have an option to specify `selector` but you can use `kubectl expose` to create a service for deployment and specify `selector`

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --target-port=8000 --selector='app=multitool'
```